# 3 ways that jQuery Mobile page transition fails

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-2013

I want to do a page transition when pushing a button, and in a js file i try the following code:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer().pagecontainer("change", "html/main.html", {
    allowSamePageTransitions: false,
    changeHash: false
});
```

Which results to *Error Loading Page* message.

The second option to do that is the following code, which also fails:

```
$.mobile.changePage("html/main.html", {
    allowSamePageTransitions: true,
    changeHash: false,
    data: loginCredentials
});
```

And the third option is:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "html/main.html", {
    data: loginCredentials,
    reload: true,
    role: "page"
});
```

The last two options show no messages at all.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

The  part of the initial html file, consists of a `data-role="page"` div, which contains "header", "content" and "footer" divs. The button is inside the "content" div:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="loginButton">Enter</a>
```

The secondary html file i am trying to switch to, contains only the "page" div with "header", "content" and "footer" as well but NOT the `<head>` part.

**UPDATE 2**

I failed to mention that the project is a mobile app, i thought the PhoneGap and Cordova tags would suggest to that.
I tested the app on a device and it works fine, using the option shown in the answer.

Comment: I wonder if it would be helpful to see your markup ... or at least how you've laid out, and any relevant code!

Comment: The index.html contains a typical single page structure that can be found here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-template.html
I will upload the button part in the main question.

Comment: I notice that jQuery Mobile is not one the tags you selected and that you've not mentioned what version you're using. Now when I saw 1.1.1 in the URL, well ... I did not know what to say! :)

Comment: I noticed that too but that was the quickest link i found for the html structure. I am using jQm 1.4.2min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, to programmatically change page you would use the following:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "html/main.html", { 
    changeHash: false 
});
```

The option `allowSamePageTransitions` is set to `false` by default, and the pagecontainer widget should already be initialized, otherwise you would not see a page. Can you confirm that `html/mail.html` actually exists or that it's URL is correct.

**Reference:**

```
http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/
```

Comment: That doesnt work either. I get the Error Loading Page message. I actually want the allowSamePageTransition set to true. The "html/main.html" exists.
What do you mean that the pagecontainer widget should already be initialized?

Comment: By writing `.pagecontainer().pagecontainer(...)` I understood that the first `.pagecontainer()` is to initialize it .. pardon me if I am mistaken. Do you have dev tools to determine why *Error Loading Page* is displayed?

Comment: Actually i have not initialized the widget. Should i do that?
And no, i dont have dev tools to determine why Error Loading Page is displayed.

Comment: Take a look at this very simplistic setup: http://71.172.176.193/ .... click enter ... you have to refresh the page to try again ... view the source.

Comment: I use Chrome's tools, and with the code you sent i see this message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/users/******/html/main.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You have to use an actual server to run your pages from .. put your page on a server and you should be good to go.

Comment: But this is supposed to be part of a mobile app. I am building it in VS using PhoneGap.

Comment: Even in VS there's an option of starting a server and running your app from there. Sorry buddy, that's just how it works .... you just cannot test from your local. Had you provided all this information at the start, we would have saved you a lot of time. It's good to be upfront with vital information like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56799/discussion-between-johnnaras-and-user3558931).